# FlipClock JS: Start personalized countdown starting from a specific date

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I'm using FlipClock.js to do a 30-hour countdown and, when it reaches zero, add one to another counter and the countdown will restart.
Currently I was able to arm both the counter and the countdown, using smaller time periods to test if they work.
The problem is that both are restarted each time the browser refreshes. How can I define a start date for both clocks?

The next code counts down one minute instead of thirty minutes and the counter adds one every three seconds instead of every thirty hours.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../compiled/flipclock.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../compiled/flipclock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clock1" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="clock2" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        clock1 = new FlipClock($('.clock1'), 60, {
            clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
            autoStart: true,
            countdown: true,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    clock.setTime(61);
                    clock.start();
                }
            }
        });

    });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock2;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        clock2 = $('.clock2').FlipClock({
            clockFace: 'Counter',
            autoStart: false,
        });

        setInterval(function(){
                clock2.increment();
        }, 3000);

    });

</script>

</body>
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: What backend processing are you using? PHP, .NET, Node? What database? SQL, MySQL, etc? Basic HTML with jQuery does not have any ability to perform data persistence so you can use just those two.

Comment: @Azeame Thank you! I think that using only HTML and JQuery I can do the counter that shows how many times from a specific date thirty hours have passed. I'm self-taught and I'm just starting with JS and JQuery ...